# How do I get specific error details from send_to by boost::asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to send TCP messages through boost::asio raw sockets.
My packets are based on this source: https://github.com/pfpacket/SYN-flood

I checked the binary output of IP und TCP packet generators and these messages look valid. Also the raw socket function for TCP looks fine.

```
45 10 00 28 00 00 40 00
40 06 A5 18 08 08 08 08
0B 0B 07 01 11 AD 15 B3
00 00 17 AA 00 00 00 00
50 02 10 00 3E BD 00 00
```

Anyway if I send this to the socket by the send_to function I receive the error:

> send_to: Ein ungültiges Argument wurde angegeben

English translation: "Used a non valid argument"

I have no more idea, where there is a problem. I need more details to the relating problem.

How can I receive more specific error messages from send_to()? What can I do next?

```
int main() {

this->port = "5555";
this->target = "11.11.7.1";

try {

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    raw_tcp::socket socket(io_service, raw_tcp::v4());  

    socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::ip_hdrincl(true));
    raw_tcp::resolver resolver(io_service); 

    raw_tcp::resolver::query query( this->target , boost::lexical_cast< std::string >(  this->port ));
    raw_tcp::endpoint destination = *resolver.resolve( query ); 

    boost::asio::streambuf request_buffer;
    std::ostream os(&request_buffer);

    //creates the ipheader and tcp packet and forward it to buffer os
    set_syn_segment(os);

    socket.send_to(request_buffer.data(), destination);         

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asio's error detection and reporting is a fairly thin layer, often propagating all information it has been provided by the underlying system call.  On failure Asio will populate a `boost::system::error_code` if the application is capable of receiving it, such as for asynchronous operations or synchronous operation overloads with the `error_code` parameter; otherwise it will throw an exception containing the `error_code`.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) explicitly mentions asynchronous operations, but the same *"as if"* behavior is often applicable to synchronous operations:

> Unless otherwise noted, when the behaviour of an asynchronous operation is defined "as if" implemented by a POSIX function, the handler will be invoked with a value of type `error_code` that corresponds to the failure condition described by POSIX for that function, if any. Otherwise the handler will be invoked with an implementation-defined `error_code` value that reflects the operating system error.
>
> Asynchronous operations will not fail with an error condition that indicates interruption by a signal (POSIX `EINTR`). Asynchronous operations will not fail with any error condition associated with non-blocking operations (POSIX `EWOULDBLOCK`, `EAGAIN` or `EINPROGRESS`; Windows `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` or `WSAEINPROGRESS`).

To further investigate an error, consider using the [BSD API mapping documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html) to determine which OS calls are being made.  One can then use the appropriate OS documentation to determine the conditions for which an error occurs and the values.  The mapping between error codes and Boost.Asio error codes is located within [`asio/error.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/asio/error.hpp#L115), but the mapping is normally fairly straight forward.

In the case of [`sendto()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendto.2.html), a return value of `EINVAL` may not provide insightful information.  One could further diagnose the problem via attaching a debugger and examining the arguments for validity when Asio makes the [system call to `sendto()`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L1270-L1304).